# Hyper v manager not connecting to, windows hyper v server 2016

Tags: hyper-v-server-2016

I have the gui less hyper v server installed, i am trying to connect to it through hyper v manger on my windows 10 pc, but i keep getting errors.

some things i have already done:

- Enable-PSRemoting
- Enable-WSManCredSSP on client and server

I have followed numerous articles and done many other things, but the current error im stuck on is

[image]

I have made sure the remote services are running, and firewall rules are disabled

Comment: Is this in an Active Directory environment?  Have you checked the event logs on both the client and the server for any error messages that show up when you attempt to connect?

Comment: What is the output of: `winrm id /r:[servername]`

Answer (score 0):

Not related to Hyper-V but trying to enable remote management for PowerShell I faced similar error messages. This two links solved my issue. Maybe you could give them a chance in the Hyper-V Server:

First one is kind of prerequisite:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/87066-setting-up-psremoting-remotely

The second one is the actual MS guide for enabling psremote by setting up winrm.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx